# valores check y default

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Tengo un store para guardar registros, quisiera saber como puedo hacerle para tener valores `check` pero si no ingreso ningun valor tener un `default`

Intenté ponerlos fuera del store haciendo `alter table` pero me sale un error:

> ```
> clasula defualt interfiere con clausula check.
> ```

```
create table dulces
(
id int not null, 
nombre varchar(20),
tipo varchar(15),
proveedor varchar(20),
fechacaducidad datetime not null,
);

alter table dulces add constraint ck_tipo check(tipo='a' or tipo='b' or tipo='c' or tipo='d')

alter table dulces add constraint df_tipo default 'n/a'

create procedure spInsertDulces(@id , @nombre varchar(20),@tipo varchar(15),@proveedor varchar(20),@fechacaducidad datetime)
as begin
if NOT EXISTS (select* from dulces where id=@id)
begin 
insert to dulces(id , nombre ,tipo ,@proveedor ,fechacaducidad)
values(@id , @nombre ,@tipo ,@proveedor ,getdate())
end
```

Comment: No me queda nada clara tu pregunta, podrías ampliarla y pegar el código que has escrito hasta ahora?

Comment: Puse el codigo de lo que llevo compañero , Intente poner valores check y default a la columna tipo pero al hacerlo con los alter y si ponia default me marcaba, quiero poner en el store valores check y si no pongo nada agarre el valor por default

    clausula default interfiere con clausula check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un conflicto entre el valor default del campo y las clausulas `CHECK`. En esta última debieras agregar como válido el valor default "n/a", por ejemplo así:

```
alter table dulces add constraint ck_tipo check(tipo='a' or tipo='b' or tipo='c' or tipo='d' or tipo='n/a')
alter table dulces add constraint df_tipo default 'n/a' for tipo
```